# Android mystery of view changing class

Tags: android, layout

Code:

```
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText(m.group());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int iDELETE_AFTER_TEST_ID;

        if(bLast != null){
            /*
             * Add a new move button
             */
            iId = bLast.getId();
            lP.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, iId);
            bLast = b;
            bLast.setId(iId + 1);
            iDELETE_AFTER_TEST_ID = iId + 1; 
        }else{
            /*
             * Add the first of the move buttons
             */
            bLast = b;
            bLast.setId(R.id.base_button_arrangement_id);
            lP.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

            iDELETE_AFTER_TEST_ID = R.id.base_button_arrangement_id;
        }

        b.setLayoutParams(lP);
        b.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 50);
        Log.d(TAG, " going to add = " + b.getId() + " class = " + b.getClass());
        rl.addView(b);
        mNumberofMoveOptions++;



        View v = findViewById(iDELETE_AFTER_TEST_ID);

        if(v != null){
            if(v.getClass() == Button.class){
                Log.d(TAG, " id = " + b.getId() + " class = " + b.getClass());
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Corruption has occured - not button type: " + 
                        iDELETE_AFTER_TEST_ID + " class: " + v.getClass());
            }
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, "Corruption has occured - view is null: " + iDELETE_AFTER_TEST_ID);
        }
```

Debug:

going to add = 2130968581 class = class android.widget.Button

Corruption has occured - not button type: 2130968581 class: class android.widget.TextView

Question:

So even though the debug clearly shows the widget getting created as a Button, when I query it directly afterwards it has been converted or changed into a TextView. Am I querying incorrectly, or is the ID getting recycled or is something else happening?

Buttons that I create before an after this particular one work perfectly fine and are created as and remain of the Button widget type.

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: There is no question in your post. If you don't ask a specific question we won't be able to help you

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear. I've edited the post to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Murphy kindly answered on another board.

The reason appears to be that fact that the seed of the ID's is driven by a tool generated Id.

Using a user defined Id seems to sort out this issue and some other random problems I was having that would not appear initially to be related at all but actually were.